# How to group a variable in R: unused argument (RM = 3)

Tags: r

I am new to r language. I am working on a data and I need to convert a column in my data into two groups (location 3 or not). The column currently has four locations (1,2,3,& 4). I wrote an if else code in order to accomplish this, but I got an error code:

**Error in colnames(RM = 3) : unused argument (RM = 3)**

Here is my code:

```
if (colnames(RM=3)) {
return(location=3)
} else {
location=!3
}
```

Here is a sample data

```
V1. V2. V3. V4. V5. V6. V7. V8
-64 -56 -61 -66 -71 -82 -81 1
-68 -57 -61 -65 -71 -85 -85 2
-63 -60 -60 -67 -76 -85 -84 3
-61 -60 -68 -62 -77 -90 -80 4
-63 -65 -60 -63 -77 -81 -87 1
-64 -55 -63 -66 -76 -88 -83 1
-65 -61 -65 -67 -69 -87 -84 2
-61 -63 -58 -66 -74 -87 -82 3
-65 -60 -59 -63 -76 -86 -82 4
-62 -60 -66 -68 -80 -86 -91 1
-67 -61 -62 -67 -77 -83 -91 1
-65 -59 -61 -67 -72 -86 -81 1
-63 -57 -61 -65 -73 -84 -84 1
```

Column V8 is the outcome. How can I make the outcome recognize (3) and (!3), i.e 1,2,&4 grouped together.

Comment: can you show us what kind of R-object you would like to be the result of your operation?

Comment: @Sirius, if you mean data type, it will be numeric.

Comment: `V8` is your expected outcome right? Can you explain the output for first few rows? How do your get output as 1, 2 3 , 4, 1, 1 in first 6 rows?

Comment: @JimmyRoberts just create a data block in your quetsion showing the data you want this to produce

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your question and taking a guess here, it seems like you want to apply a rule where if the value in V8 is 3, i.e. location 3 then print 3 otherwise print "not 3".

if that is the case, you can try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

    df <- data.frame(
      V1 = c(-64L,-68L,-63L,-61L,-63L,-64L,-65L,
             -61L,-65L,-62L,-67L,-65L,-63L),
      V2 = c(-56L,-57L,-60L,-60L,-65L,-55L,-61L,
             -63L,-60L,-60L,-61L,-59L,-57L),
      V3 = c(-61L,-61L,-60L,-68L,-60L,-63L,-65L,
             -58L,-59L,-66L,-62L,-61L,-61L),
      V4 = c(-66L,-65L,-67L,-62L,-63L,-66L,-67L,
             -66L,-63L,-68L,-67L,-67L,-65L),
      V5 = c(-71L,-71L,-76L,-77L,-77L,-76L,-69L,
             -74L,-76L,-80L,-77L,-72L,-73L),
      V6 = c(-82L,-85L,-85L,-90L,-81L,-88L,-87L,
             -87L,-86L,-86L,-83L,-86L,-84L),
      V7 = c(-81L,-85L,-84L,-80L,-87L,-83L,-84L,
             -82L,-82L,-91L,-91L,-81L,-84L),
      V8 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L))


df <- df %>%
mutate(location = if_else(V8 == 3,"3","Not 3"))
```

This will print out the following:
[image]

Let me know if that's what you're after, good luck!

Comment: thank you. The table is exactly what I am looking for. Although, I got an error message - Error in df %>% mutate(location = if_else(V8 == 3, "3", "Not 3")) : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: i think you also need to import the "magrittr" package via library(magrittr), if you don't have it you can install it via install.packages('magrittr')

Comment: Thank you so much @dswdsyd, it worked after I installed "Magrittr"